# saml2 application not supported

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, saml, saml-2.0, aris

In my company we're setting up SAML2 SSO for all applications. One application (ARIS Publisher Server) do not support SAML but only Kerberos.

In this case, what should we do to set up SAML2 SSO for this application ?

In advance, thank you for your help !

Zack

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a SAML client side stack to the application.

There's a list here - [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html) .

The other option is to deliver this out of an IDaaS product e.g. Auth0, Okta etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help,i will try this !